# Polynomal functions on matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, polynomials, education

I'm a TA of the linear algebra course for undergraduate freshmen. There is an exercise in the textbook:

> Let $A$ be a complex matrix of size $n\times n$. For every polynomials (remark: we only consider polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$) $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, let $f(x)=p(x)+q(x),g(x)=p(x)q(x)$. Prove that $f(A)=p(A)+q(A),g(A)=p(A)q(A)$.

What does it mean? As abstract functions from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ to $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, these consequences should be automatically satisfied. I don't see there is anything to "proof".

Comment: Nevertheless we would like to see a formal proof. If $A^2=0$, and $p(x)=q(x)=x$, then $p(A)q(A)=A^2=0$, but $g(x)$ is not the zero polynomial, but rather $g(x)=x^2$. So there is a difference. But of course we have $g(A)=0$.

Comment: The analogous statement for polynomials in two variables is false. So there is something to explain in why this doesn't happen for polynomials in one variable.